# Custom button on UIKeyboard

Tags: iphone, uikit, uikeyboard

I am trying to add a custom done button on the UIKeyboard (the number pad specifically). I have followed all the examples to do this online but I can't get the button to appear above the keyboard. Below is my code (mainly patched together from online examples):

```
    UIButton *doneButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
doneButton.frame = CGRectMake(214, 427, 106, 53);
doneButton.adjustsImageWhenHighlighted = NO;
[doneButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"DoneUp.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[doneButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"DoneDown.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
[doneButton addTarget:self action:@selector(doneButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

UIWindow *tempWindow = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows] objectAtIndex:1];
UIView *keyboard;
for(int i=0; i<[tempWindow.subviews count]; i++) 
{
    keyboard = [tempWindow.subviews objectAtIndex:i];
    if([[keyboard description] hasPrefix:@"<UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad"] == YES)
        [keyboard addSubview:doneButton];
}
```

Am I doing something wrong?

(This code is called after the keyboard is displayed).

EDIT:

I am showing the keypad in a modal view controller which is the child of a UINavigationController. In all the sample code I've tried the problem seems to be with this line:

```
        if([[keyboard description] hasPrefix:@"<UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad"] == YES)
```

which is returning NO. I have tested this using the UIKeyboardDidShow notification so the keyboard is definitely visible when the code is called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the solution. In iOS4.0 Apple changed the description of the keyboard so you now have to use UIPeripheralHostView (this is clearly not the best way to implement this solution if Apple can change that value at any time). My positioning of the button was also off as I was positioning the y coordinate against the whole view instead of just the keyboard. Here is the final code:

```
- (void)keyboardDidShow:(NSNotification *)note {


// create custom button
UIButton *doneButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
doneButton.frame = CGRectMake(215, 163, 106, 53);
doneButton.adjustsImageWhenHighlighted = NO;
[doneButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"DoneUp.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[doneButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"DoneDown.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
[doneButton addTarget:self action:@selector(doneButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

UIWindow* tempWindow;

UIView* keyboard;

for(int c = 0; c < [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows] count]; c ++)
{
    tempWindow = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows] objectAtIndex:c];

    for(int i = 0; i < [tempWindow.subviews count]; i++)
    {
        keyboard = [tempWindow.subviews objectAtIndex:i];

        if([[keyboard description] hasPrefix:@"<UIPeripheralHostView"] == YES)
        {
            [keyboard addSubview:doneButton];
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: This seems to work differently on the device. This solution only works on the simulator.

Comment: The solution doesn't work for sim here.  I'm running iOS 6.1.3

Comment: @mskw It worked on iOS 4 but I'm sure things have changed. I don't use this method anymore. I just create a tool bar with the done button and when the keyboard is animated in I also animate in the toolbar and position it just about the keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

The way you are trying is hard-code hacking and violating HIG I think.

If you want to customize keyboard, you should create your own keyboard and set it to your `UIResponder`'s `inputView`.

Comment: I don't think it is violating the HIG. The keypad will appear identical to the normal one but will have a button replaced. Creating my own keyboard would work but it is a much more time consuming solution and as I am only using this is one screen in my app (to let the user enter a passcode) it is not worth the time it would take.

Comment: You are poking holes on the system keyboard, which I think is not something Apple will be happy to see.